# How to resolve #hyperledger-Composer V0.14 unmarshalling error

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-composer

I have just moved from V0.13.2 to V0.14.2 and am now getting following error in event processing. The error appears to be in the composer-client code, not mine. Any ideas on resolving? Events are still being posted and processed by my app, so my code still appears to work, but the presence of these error messages is troubling and their volume is overwhelming my console window.

```
error: [EventHub.js]: on.data - Error unmarshalling transaction= TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSerializer' of null
    at events.forEach (<path>Z2B_Master/Chapter12/node_modules/composer-client/lib/businessnetworkconnection.js:483:73)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at HLFConnection.connection.on (<path>Z2B_Master/Chapter12/node_modules/composer-client/lib/businessnetworkconnection.js:482:29)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at HLFConnection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at ChainCodeCBE.ccEvent.eventHubs.(anonymous function).registerChaincodeEvent [as onEvent] (<path>Z2B_Master/Chapter12/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:231:22)
    at <path>Z2B_Master/Chapter12/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/EventHub.js:810:12
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at EventHub._processChainCodeOnEvents (<path>Z2B_Master/Chapter12/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/EventHub.js:808:14)
    at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (<path>Z2B_Master/Chapter12/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/EventHub.js:311:10)
```

This error is not present using identical code in V0.13.

All events are emitted via a single function in the sample.js file. A transaction calls the function as in the following example:

```
/**
 * create an order to purchase
 * @param {org.acme.Z2BTestNetwork.CreateOrder} purchase - the order to be processed
 * @transaction
 */
function CreateOrder(purchase) {
    purchase.order.buyer = purchase.buyer;
    purchase.order.amount = purchase.amount;
    purchase.order.financeCo = purchase.financeCo;
    purchase.order.created = new Date().toISOString();
    purchase.order.status = JSON.stringify(orderStatus.Created);
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.Z2BTestNetwork.Order')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            return assetRegistry.update(purchase.order)
            .then (function (_res) 
            {
                z2bEmit('Created', purchase.order);
                return (_res);
            }).catch(function(error){return(error);});
        });
}
```

Each transaction calls the z2bEmit function with a unique `_event` string.

```
function z2bEmit(_event, _order)
{
    var method = 'z2bEmit';
    var factory = getFactory();
    var z2bEvent = factory.newEvent(ns, _event);
    z2bEvent.orderID = _order.$identifier;
    z2bEvent.buyerID = _order.buyer.$identifier;
    emit(z2bEvent);
    return
}
```

`_order` is a defined asset in the cto file, `_event` is a defined event in the cto file.

The client side code has a single routine, executed once, to set up monitoring:

```
/**
 * Register for all of the available Z2BEvents
 * @param {express.req} req - the inbound request object from the client
 * @param {express.res} res - the outbound response object for communicating back to client
 * @param {express.next} next - an express service to enable post processing prior to responding to the client
*/
exports.init_z2bEvents = function (req, res, next)
{
    var method = 'init_z2bEvents';
    if (bRegistered) {res.send('Already Registered');}
    else{
        bRegistered = true;
        let _conn = svc.createAlertSocket();
        let businessNetworkConnection;
        businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
        // following line added to deal with eventListener error message that more eventListeners needed to be added
        businessNetworkConnection.setMaxListeners(50);
        return businessNetworkConnection.connect(config.composer.connectionProfile, config.composer.network, config.composer.adminID, config.composer.adminPW)
        .then(() => {
            businessNetworkConnection.on('event', (event) => {_monitor(svc.al_connection, svc.f_connection, event); });
            res.send('event registration complete');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(method+' business network connection failed'+error.message); 
            res.send(method+' business network connection failed'+error.message);
        });
    }
}
```

The connectionProfile is 'hlfv1'

and a single monitor routine, which figures out what kind of event has been posted and then uses a web socket to send that info to a browser so that an alert icon can be posted or updated. A shortened version of that function follows. _conn _f_conn continue to work correctly. The _event information is being passed in and continues to parse correctly. The eventhub.js messages appear on every alert, irrespective of how long the program runs.

```
/**
 * _monitor
 * @param {web.socket} _conn - web socket connection for general alerts
 * @param {web.socket} _f_conn - web socket for finance alerts
 * @param {org.acme.z2bNetwork.Event} _event - the event just emitted
 * 
 */
function _monitor(_conn, _f_conn, _event)
{
    var method = '_monitor';
    console.log(method+ ' _event received: '+_event.$type+' for Order: '+_event.orderID);
    var event = {};
    event.type = _event.$type;
    event.orderID = _event.orderID;
    event.ID = _event.buyerID;
    _conn.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(event));

    switch (_event.$type)
    {
        case 'Created':
        break;
        case 'Bought':
        case 'PaymentRequested':
            event.ID = _event.sellerID;
            _conn.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(event));
            event.ID = _event.financeCoID;
            _f_conn.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(event));
        break;
        case 'Ordered':
        case 'Cancelled':
        case 'Backordered':
            event.ID = _event.sellerID;
            _conn.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(event));
            event.ID = _event.providerID;
            _conn.sendUTF(JSON.stringify(event));
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: There's not enough information to determine what the issue might be. Can you provide a cutdown recreate of your problem ?

Comment: added code to demonstrate how I am processing events.

Comment: Would you also be able to provide failing client side code ? The error you are getting is around the fact there isn't a business network, which might indicate a timing issue between events being emitted and connection creation.

Comment: David, although I added the client side code, I did some testing before posting this question. The testing included removing the client-side monitoring code. That had no impact on the errors being generated. The only way to stop the errors was to comment out the emit statement.

Comment: But the error you have posted is client side, so I was trying to understand what you were doing on the client side in order for the composer code to have a problem. Somewhere a listener has been registered for events but when it comes to process the event the businessnetworkname is not available.

Answer (score 1):

While unable to determine the root cause of this problem, it has gone away with the release of (and upgrade to) hyperledger-composer V0.15.2.